# jquery css position fixed

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu toggle on mobile views that has the menu completely overlay the content, but if the user tries to scroll down the menu, the background content scrolls. I'd like to make the background content fixed to eliminate this problem and have written this bit of code, but it doesn't work:

```
var $ = jQuery;
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
$(document).ready(function(){
if (viewportWidth < 769){
    alert(viewportWidth);
    if ($(".sidebar-primary").show() ){
        $('top-nav').css({ "position": "fixed" });
    } else {
        $('top-nav').css({ "position": "relative" });
    }
}
});
```

The site is hearthayward.com. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the squiggly brackets around the arguments

Comment: Add overflow: hidden to body yo fix the background during viewport less than 769 ..$('body').css( "overflow": "hidden" );

Comment: I'm assuming you mean these { "position": "fixed" }, so I removed those but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` are fine they are being used properly. The problem is most likely the fact that you are calling `top-nav` WITHOUT the `#` for IDS or without `.` for classes.

**so change:**

```
$('top-nav')
```

**to this for classes:**

```
$('.top-nav')
```

**or for an id:**

```
$('#top-nav')
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO A**

```
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

WHEN the overlay content is `shown` onlick and when overlay is hidden again do `overflow :auto`

Comment: Cool, that works except now the sidebar is showing the minute the page loads instead of when the user clicks.

Comment: remove your `if ($(".sidebar-primary").show() ){` might be causing issue

Comment: put your `.sidebar-primary{display:none}` in css and when onclick do `$('.sidebar-primary').toggle();` and remove your `    if ($(".sidebar-primary").show() ){
        $('top-nav').css({ "position": "fixed" });
    } else {
        $('top-nav').css({ "position": "relative" });
    }` code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`$('top-nav').css({ "position": "fixed" });`

change the ":" to a "," and drop your braces so that it reads as follows:

`$('top-nav').css("position", "fixed");`

Do the same for your second line.